# marker on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Please how develop on the map, when you make a click on the screen (the map) it displays a marker of the selected area and after when you click the marker then it displays a new screen that contains information on the selected area such as longitude and latitude

Comment: Well, read the docs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lukas is right. First read the documentation. You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html). 
To give you a head start here is how you can add a marker at given lat, longitude with a headind string and the detailed string ( can be address etc)

```
 // Function to call
    private void addMarker(GoogleMap map, double lati, double longi,
                           String titl, String snippt) {
      map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
                                       .title(titl)
                                       .snippet(snippt));
    }
```

Here is how I call the function with lat and lng as double values:

```
    addMarker(map, lat, lng,"Address Heading", "Data string");
```

'map' is a GoogleMap object. Here is how I've initialized the object:

```
     SupportMapFragment mapFrag=
         (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     map=mapFrag.getMap();
     map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
     map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
     map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

This is just a sniplet of the whole code to give you some understanding of it. Its a good idea to start with the documentation though.